# I there a way to create forum post using discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to create a forum post using **discord.py**, is this possible?

I am trying to use discors.py to create a new forum post in a certain case, I want to know if it is possible to use discord.py on a forum post.

I'd like to receive an answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you look more into the discord.py documentation, it‘ll help to answer most of the questions

To create a thread (post) in a forum use [`ForumChannel#create_thread`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.ForumChannel.create_thread)